# Is there a way to open all files in a directory in the current workspace using the VS Code CLI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I want to open all files under `/var/log/my_program/` in my current open workspace. To be clear, I want to open the files from this directory while keeping the files that are already open in my current workspace open as well.

e.g. if I have `~/hello-world.html` open, I would like to open `/var/log/my_program/error.log` and `/var/log/my_program/access.log` in the workspace as well, having a total of 3 files open at the same time in the same window/workspace.

if I run `code /var/log/my_program/*` it will open up a new window with all of the files open from that directory. i.e. `hello-world.html` will be in one window and `error.log` and `access.log` will be in a new window

if I run `code -r /var/log/my_program/*` it will overwrite my current workspace with the files from that directory. i.e. `hello-world.html` will no longer be open in any window, and `error.log` and `access.log` will be open in my original workspace window.

I want to be able to keep the state of my current workspace AND open the files from the `/var/log/my_program/` directory. i.e. I would like `hello-world.html` to stay open in the workspace AND have `error.log` and `access.log` open as well.

I would like to add that this is just a simplified example of what I am trying to do. I understand it would be easy enough to just open these two files easily in the command line, but the actual files in the dir I want to open could be several and all with timestamps in their names, so I cant easily open them by name

Is this possible? Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
I am really looking for a solution using the CLI. I am running a command similar to `rm /var/log/my_program/*; systemctl restart my_program; code /var/log/my_program/*`. This is so the dir doesnt get full of old log files, and I can see the new log files opened after I have restarted the process for `my_program`

The reasoning for all of this is to make my debugging routine less cumbersome, e.g. without mouse clicks or gui interaction

Answer (score 0):

In VS CODE itself there is a keyboard shortcut that might be helpful:
`ctrl + r` 
Which will open a drop down of folders.
Once you arrow down/up to the desired folder, you have two options:
Click `enter` to open the new folder instead of the current workspace, or
`ctrl + enter` to open a new folder in addition to the current open workspace

Comment: awesome, thank you! Appreciate the response, but I am really looking for a solution using the CLI. I am running a command similar to `rm /var/log/my_program/*; systemctl restart my_program; code /var/log/my_program*`. This is so the dir doesnt get full of old log files, and i can see the new log files opened after I have restarted the process for my_program

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you want to use the `--add` argument. You can run `code --reuse-window --add <path>` to open the folder at `<path>` in the current workspace. The shortened version would be `code -r -a <path>`.